# How to disable auto new line when type { twice in vim?

Tags: vim

You know,in Django template, the variables are wraped up by {{ }},but it seems that in Vim(vi and gvim are the same),after you type {},and type another {,it will auto insert a new line instead of { . Does anyone knows how to disable it?

Comment: Neither vi nor gvim do this for me. Does this only happen in some particular mode? What about when you edit a .txt file? Sounds like some effect of a plugin.

Comment: Yes，it is the problem of autoclose.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this autoclose plugin for certain filetypes, like for example just for .c and .h files, you could drop it in `.vim/ftplugin/c_autoclose.vim` and `.vim/ftplugin/h_autoclose.vim`, maybe symlinking it from one central location.

It seems weird to me that a plugin with such a big impact wouldn't have a switch to temporarily disable it. It would definitely be an improvement to this script if you modified it to add a `b:disable_autoclose` variable (`b:` variables can have different values in different buffers) and made it respect that value. Then you could do

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.html let b:disable_autoclose=1
```

or just make a keymapping to toggle it so you can have it for any embedded CSS or JS and disable it for Django.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that feature is not configurable. You may have to disable it by editing the source code of autoclose. Only two lines of code need changing.

Change this:

```
88         "inoremap <silent> { {<C-R>=<SID>CloseStackPush('}')<CR>
89         inoremap <silent> { <C-R>=<SID>OpenSpecial('{','}')<CR>
```

to

```
88         inoremap <silent> { {<C-R>=<SID>CloseStackPush('}')<CR>
89         "inoremap <silent> { <C-R>=<SID>OpenSpecial('{','}')<CR>
```

Besides, you can turn off autoclose temporarily by `<leader>a`.